# How to equally scale imagebutton and imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Here full xml file but they are not equally scaled

I mean lets say both images are 500 px width and height however if screen resolution is 700 px they are not equally scaled to 350 px and i want to achieve it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Pokemon"
android:background="@drawable/pokemon_monstermmorpg_bg_land">>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/application_text"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton_register"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/image_button"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

    />
```

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand the question what is the result you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

Put your imageview and imagebutton in `RelativeLayout` and set the width of the `ImageButton` to `match_parent` and change the `BackGround` of `ImageButton` to the `drawable` from `src`

Comment: Put it in one more relative layout as you have the background image also right

Comment: nothing changed : http://orig08.deviantart.net/54ef/f/2015/073/8/c/bothing_changed_by_monstermmorpg-d8lqquh.png

Comment: Not working again unfortunately : http://orig11.deviantart.net/d7d5/f/2015/073/1/2/not_working_again_by_monstermmorpg-d8lqv5w.png

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG this is happening because of your drawable, i suggest you to have a separate drawable bg for and background and set the text on the button separately

Answer (score 0):

you can use the weight sum for this.